# How can I disable float conversion in inputs with a digit followed by f?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to collect input that will assign digits (or decimal numbers) to a double and then assign any remaining characters to a string.

In Xcode, this code terminates early for inputs like `0f` or `9feet`. It works as expected for other characters like `12k` and `9cm`. I imagine this is because `f` after a digit automatically widens the number type to `float`. But changing the type of `numeric_value` to `float` didn't solve the problem. Anyway, how can I overcome this? I want to be able to accept inputs like `90ft` so that `numeric_value==90` and `unit==ft`.

I don't have the same problem using [Repl.it C++ REPL](https://repl.it/languages/cpp).

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    while (true) {
        double numeric_value;
        string unit = "";

        if (cin >> numeric_value >> unit) {
            cout << numeric_value << unit << "\n";
        } else {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember some long-ago bugs where certain characters, the f for example, could get sucked in to a floating point read. How old is the compiler being used by xcode?

Comment: Non bug, you'll have problems with stuff like 10ergs due to parsing for exponents. `>>` is expecting to find something like 10e7 and gets mad when it spots the r.

Comment: One option is to separate the value from the unit with a space. Another option is to define the separation between the value and unit yourself. Look for some digits, then an optional dot, then some more digits. Maybe handle scientific notation as well. The remaining characters are the unit. You could do that a little differently. Start at the end and work backwards until you reach a digit.

Comment: @user4581301 it's a bug. [`cin` parses the input string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) with [`std::num_get::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) (in stage 3) and the input format of floating-point types never includes the suffix `f`. It also can't cast the type just based on the input format string

Comment: @phuclv That second comment of mine is tragically unclear, but meant as a warning that not all <number><string> floating point combinations are parsable the way the asker needs. f is a bug. e is not a bug.

Comment: @IndianaKernick Based on your suggestion, it seems the answer is to accept  input as a string and parse it with a [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

Comment: You could use regex but it's overkill for something this simple.